# in angular why not data-ng-* but ng-*

Tags: angularjs

I've come to know that **data-ng-**`*` is validation-friendly. But I've come across many places where I see snippets having **ng-**`*` over **data-ng-***. Even the snippets in the angular official sites. Why is it so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [HTML 5.1 Editor's Draft](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/dom.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-*-attributes),

> 3.2.5.9 *Embedding custom non-visible data with the [`data-*`](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/dom.html#attr-data-*) attributes*
>
> A **custom data attribute** is an attribute in no namespace whose name
>   starts with the string "data-", has at least one character after the
>   hyphen, is
>   [XML-compatible](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/infrastructure.html#xml-compatible),
>   and [contains no uppercase ASCII
>   letters](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/infrastructure.html#uppercase-ascii-letters).

And the official [angularjs documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive):

> ## What are Directives?
>
> At a high level, directives are markers on a DOM element (such as an
>   attribute, element name, comment or CSS class) that tell AngularJS's
>   **HTML compiler** (`$compile`) to attach a specified behavior to that DOM element or even transform the DOM element and its children.
>
> Angular comes with a set of these directives built-in, like `ngBind`,
>   `ngModel`, and `ngClass`. Much like you create controllers and
>   services, you can create your own directives for Angular to use. When
>   Angular [bootstraps](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/bootstrap) your
>   application, the [HTML
>   compiler](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/compiler) traverses the DOM
>   matching directives against the DOM elements.

And farther down the page:

> **Best Practice**: Prefer using the dash-delimited format (e.g. `ng-bind` for `ngBind`). If you want to use an HTML validating tool,
>   you can instead use the `data`-prefixed version (e.g. `data-ng-bind`
>   for `ngBind`). The other forms shown above are accepted for legacy
>   reasons but we advise you to avoid them.

So directives of the form `data-ng-*` are only necessary if you want your HTML to validate. Otherwise, it's "deprecated". Use `ng-*` instead.

Answer (score 2):

To embed custom non visible data we use data-*. hence using  data-ng-*  is suggested instead of  ng-app To make it a valid html template.
Please refer : [W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/elements.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-attributes)